# Where can I find up-to-date status for implementation of WASI proposals?

Tags: runtime, webassembly, wasi

I am exploring standalone WASM/WASI runtimes like Wasmtime/Wasmer and I am wondering where can I find up-to-date information regarding their current implementation of the WASI proposals?

I tried their website docs with no luck.

I am looking for running WASM/WASI standalone not embedded.

Many thanks in advance.